# Change print page title font size by CSS

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to change font size of header(Page title) and footer(Page URL and Pagination) print by browser in print by CSS?

Actually I've a big title in my page. But i want to display it completely by reducing it's size.

Is there any way to reduce font-size of title as we can set other property of page ie.

```
@page {
  margin-top: 2cm;
  margin-bottom: 2cm; 
  margin-left: 3cm; 
  margin-right: 3cm;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can try this:

```
@media print {
    h1 {
        font-size: 12pt;
    }
}
```

Otherwise you can checkout this tutorial for more information on CSS media:
http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/css-tutorial/css-media-types.php

Comment: it'll define heading size not page title

Comment: @Tarun did you find any solution dear ?